# cython array in pure python mode

Tags: python, cython

I wish to unpack columnar data coming through a socket - a bunch of ints, then a bunch of floats etc., so it is faster than with `struct.unpack`

I was thinking of using a cython array, but couldn't find how to use it inside a regular python script, as the cython example uses
`from cpython cimport array`

I was wondering whether it is possible to define a cython array in pure python mode (something akin to `cython.locals`), and if so, how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My query was about deserializing columnar data with minimal overhead.

I found the solution in pure Python to me memoryviews, using the cast() option:

```
from struct import pack, unpack

# Generate sample packed data
# data = 1,2
# pack('2i', *data)
# Result: b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00'

# Unpack sample columnar data coming from socket
socket_data = b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00'
memoryview(socket_data ).cast('i').tolist()
# Result: [1,2]
```

This allows to create a memoryview once, then unpack the data in chunks if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Cython can handle C-type arrays (i.e. pointer to memory location) and [typed memoryviews](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html). In practice the memoryviews correspond to NumPy arrays or [buffer objects](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#bufferobjects).

C-type arrays are hard to manage manually whereas NumPy arrays are more convenients in terms of memory management. In practice, the performance on NumPy arrays/memoryviews/buffer objects is the same as the storage of the data is done "à la C" anyway (a pointer to a memory location), I advise strongly to manage the data with NumPy and pass it around. Any Cython or Python code aware of the buffer protocol with allow C-speed computations provided the computational code is Cython/C/C++.

Comment: I wish to use python's own array, without numpy dependency

Comment: Although it is based on the NumPy data structure, buffer objects are part of the [Python standard](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html) and can be used independently of NumPy.